# How to crop a selected rectangle using based on mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have drawn an image on the canvas.

I want the user to click on the canvas to crop a portion of the image.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is. Please try to describe your problem more detailed. Especially the first sentence is very hard to understand.

Comment: Are you asking to crop an image? You have an image in the canvas and then you want the user to define a rectangular area in the canvas, the canvas is cropped, and then that image is maybe uploaded? The following link shows how to do image cropping using the canvas:  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an outline to get you started:**

- Draw the image onto the canvas

  ```
  var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.drawImage(yourImageObject,0,0);
  ```
- Listen for `mousedown` events.

  ```
  canvas.onmousedown=function(e){handleMouseDown(e);};
  ```
- Have the user click in the top-left `[x0,y0]` and bottom-right `[x1,y1]` corners where they want to crop and record those 2 mouse positions.
- The cropping rectangle is defined like this:

  ```
  var x=x0; 
  var y=y0;
  var width=x1-x0;
  var height=y1-y0;
  ```
- Create a second canvas element and size it to the cropping size:

  ```
  var secondCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  secondCanvas.width = width;
  secondCanvas.height = height;
  document.body.appendChile(secondCanvas);
  ```
- Use the clipping version of `drawImage` to draw the cropping rectangle from the first canvas onto the second canvas

  ```
  secondCanvas.drawImage(canvas,
      x,y,width,height,  // clip just the cropping rectangle from the first canvas
      0,0,width,height   // draw just the cropped part onto the first canvas
  );
  ```

The user's selected portion of the image is now on the second canvas.

If you want to convert the second canvas into an image object, you can do this:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src=secondCanvas.toDataURL();
function start(){
    // at this point, img contains the cropped portion of the original image 
}
```